# I want to print False values in my function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 li=[4,6,8,3,7]
 def even(x):
        if x%2==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    a=filter(even,li)
    print(a)
    print(list(a))
```

In this program, I can easily print the True values, but I want to print the False values without changed my function.
How can I do that?

Comment: `list(map(even, li))`? Or *only* the `False` values? You can use `itertools.filterfalse`, or simply use`[x for x in li if not even(x)]`

Comment: You can negate the return value of any predicate you pass to `filter`: `filter(lambda x: not even(x), li)`. (That said, why does a function named `even` return `False` for even arguments?)

Comment: Could you show us what `li` is?

Comment: li=[]
def even(x):
    if x%2==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
a=map(even,[10,11,12])
print([i for i in a if not i])

Comment: i want to print values.
not the boolian expressions @Saranya Sridharan

Comment: a=[10,11,12]
print([i for i in a if not i % 2 == 0) try this